# Transfer experience to items

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

Is there anything in the direwolf20 modpack which would allow you to transfer experience from the player to a machine or item for later use? Maybe something like a Bottle O' Enchanting which you can fill with your own experience orbs.

Answer (score 3):

With openblocks, make a tank and an XP drain (which you stand on). Connect the tank to an XP bottler, and you're done!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a XP Extractor from MineFactory Reloaded to fill an empty bucket with mob essence which you can then later consume or use in other MineFactory machines like Auto-Enchanter.